# Запретить выполнение скриптов из текстовых полей в django

Tags: python, django

Есть миксин для модели:

```
class DescriptionMixin(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание',
                                   blank=True, null=True)
```

Если сохранить в поле `description` текст с открывающимися и закрывающимися тегами script `<script>alert("test")</script>`, то при открытии модели в шаблоне выполнится скрипт. А не должен. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ запретить выполнение скриптов из текстовых полей в django? Пока не нашел способа. Спасибо.

Django 3.1

Comment: а в шаблон выводите так `{{description|safe}}`?

Comment: {{ product.description|safe }} - все верно, так

Comment: ну просто убрать `|safe` чтобы выводило как строку. Если это больше ни на что не влияет

Comment: Да, похоже в этом дело, в понедельник на работе проверю. Перечитал документацию https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe - похоже то, что нужно.